# Google Chrome Stable won't Play <audio> in Chrome App, but Chrome Beta/Dev Can

Tags: ajax, html, google-chrome, audio

I'm trying to get Google Chrome Stable(16.0.912.75) to play mp3.

**Here's My Sample Code**

```
<html><head><title></title></head>
<body>

    <audio autoplay controls src=""></audio>
    <ul>
        <li>file:///E:/Songs/Aerosmith/DreamOn.mp3</li>
        <li>file:///E:/Songs/Aerosmith/Cryin'.mp3</li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var audioElement = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
        audioElement.src="file:///E:/Songs/Aerosmith/DreamOn.mp3";
        audioElement.load();
        audioElement.play();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**THE PROBLEM**


The Above Code works Fine in Chrome Beta/Dev and Chromium Snapshots(with codecs replaced by Chrome Codecs).
But SomeHow,
The App won't play audio in Google Chrome Stable Release.
But,

*The When Directed to Unpackaged App's Code.. e.g file://D:/App/index.html
The App Plays audio*

**The Tests**

1.Specifying  src inside HTML

```
<audio autoplay controls src="file:///E:/Songs/Aerosmith/DreamOn.mp3"></audio>
```

2.Specifying  src Dynamically Through Javascript

```
$('li').click(function(){
    $('audio')[0].src=$(this).innerText;
    $('audio')[0].play();
});
```

Both Methods Fail When The Code is Loaded as a Chrome App in Google Chrome Stable

But Works Fine in Google Chrome Beta/Dev and Chromium Snapshots.

**What Could Be The Reason For This Behaviour ???**

Answer (score 0):

the most obvious reason would be, that there is a bug in the current stable which was resolved in a newer release (try canary build)